# line of code converting char to string --> foobar(string("text")+anotherString)

Tags: c++

I have a line of code that seems to convert a char array to  a string

```
foobar(string("text")+anotherString);
```

foobar expects a std::string as an argument

I've never seen a conversion done this way... what function is being called on "text". or is it some tricky way of casting?

Comment: If "foobar expects a std::string as an argument", this is not a C question :-) Removed that tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` has a constructor that takes a char-array* (assumed null-terminated), which I'm sure you have seen before:

```
std::string s1 = "hello world";
std::string s2("also hello world");  // "same thing", essentially
```

So `std::string("test")` just creates a temporary string object with value `"test"`.

Furthermore, there's a free `operator+` for `string` and `const char *` which appends the data in the char-array (again assumed null-terminated) to the string.

Equivalently you can write `std::string("test").append(anotherString)`, for the same effect (i.e. a temporary containing the two strings, concatenated).

For a list of operations supported by `std::string`, consult any decent [manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

<sub>*) or rather, "a pointer to the first element of an array of chars"</sub>

Comment: Ha ha, +1 just for the CYA footnote :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Hehe.. but there's a serious point: The constructor is *not* `template <unsigned int N> string(char const (&)[N])`, but really `string(char *)`, so you really don't need an array. If you want, `string(std::decay("test"))` would work just as well.

Comment: ...a ready CYA would probably expand on the free-operator+ vs member-operator+, but there's a time and a place...

Answer (score 1):

`string("text")` creates a temporary object string by calling its constructor and passing it `"text"`. The `+anotherString` part calls the "operator+" member function of the temporary created, which returns a string object too.
At last, foobar is called and this latter string object is passed.

It is exactly the same as:

```
string temp("text");
temp += anotherString;
foobar(temp);
```

If this helps